# HelloWorld with Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse

Running the simple `HelloWorld.java` program below (by clicking run in eclipse)

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
     System.out.println("Hello World");
   }    
}
```

after installing the latest version of Eclipse on my mac 10.7.2 yields the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like when you tell it to run you have the wrong class file selected

Click on the run icon drop down and select Run Configurations, then make sure you have the right class selected for main class.

[image: step one]
[image: step two]

Comment: dont think this is it...i still get this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Answer (score 0):

Using the default java environment that came with MacOS resolved this for me.