# How to use Eclipse and Java for Mac 10.8.1

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, terminal

When I try to do a simple "Hello World" java application I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /path/to/mainarg*
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: first.Skeleton
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I am running on Mac OS 10.8.1 and am running Java 1.6. I have checked my run configurations to make sure the main argument can be found. For the sake of simplicity I have also tried to use the default JRE of java 1.6 that is included with mac. The build configuration I have used is also correct and pointed to the right place.

When I followed [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/mac-cmd.html) tutorial online, and executed the commands over the terminal I get the same error. What am I missing? I don't think it is an Eclipse problem anymore, but something bigger. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I tried to run:

```
           public class Test{
              /* This is my first java program.
               * This will print 'Hello World' as the output
               */
                public static void main(String[]args){
                  System.out.println("Hello World");// prints Hello World
                }
           }
```

I put the code on my Desktop for simplicity. I went to /usr/tyler/desktop then made the script an executable with "javac Test.java", and when I tried to run it with "java Test.java" I then got the error.

Here are the other tutorials I have followed:

-[Java Compilation error on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946129/java-compilation-error-on-mac)

-[HelloWorld with Eclipse on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576255/helloworld-with-eclipse-on-mac)

-Along with many others from SO and elsewhere

EDIT:
   Thank you for the help. The terminal issue has been resolved. However, if anyone has any advice on what could be going wrong with Eclipse, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your code? It seems java is trying to find a class that you don't have in the build path.

Comment: Show the *exact* command line you entered, as well as the current directory where you entered the command.

Comment: Do not post code in comments. Add it to the original post (use the EDIT button)

Comment: Is there a package name? Is that the complete source code listing?

Comment: Java is a compiled language. You have to first compile your class using "javac" and then run the class by specifying the class' name (*not* its file name since that wouldn't work for jar files).

Comment: Thank you @nitind. That does resolve the terminal issue. Any idea why it would not work on Eclipse then?

Comment: @Jim Garrison. There is a packaged titled "test." The run configurations on Eclipise have been set to "test.World" and still results in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run ... 
"java Test"

You cannot execute the java code, you need to execute the compiled class file.  The java executable will look for a .class file with the name Test.

Answer (score 0):

execute or run

```
java Test
```

instead of

```
java Test.java
```